# container_run_and_commit_layer fails with: docker not found

Tags: docker, bazel

I have a problem when running `container_run_and_commit_layer`, the error message I get is

```
docker not found; do you need to manually configure the docker toolchain?
```

from what I see this is related to `DOCKER` variable not set:

```
# Resolve the docker tool path
DOCKER=""
DOCKER_FLAGS=""

if [[ -z "$DOCKER" ]]; then
    echo >&2 "error: docker not found; do you need to manually configure the docker toolchain?"
    exit 1
fi
```

I'm calling `container_repositories()` in my workspace file, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That rule requires Docker to be installed. By default, it expects to find `docker` via `$PATH`. When it doesn't, you get that error.

The [Setup section](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#setup) of the rules_docker documentation lists all the optional tools, and shows how to set custom paths to them. Some of the rules_docker rules don't need any of those, so they'll work fine. The rules which do need those tools give errors like this when run when the given tools aren't installed.

If you install `docker` now, you might have to `bazel clean --expunge` after installing it to ensure the repository rule is evaluated again.

Comment: Thanks for that info, it pointed me to more severe issue.